# Component auth has not been registered yet

Tags: angular, firebase, deployment, build

When I try ng serve (lench angular app in localhost) all work great, but when I try to build my app  (create dist/projet-name) using (ng build --prod and ng build --watch) and trying deploy in lite-server I had this issue

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Component auth has not been registered yet
Error: Component auth has not been registered yet
at pe.initialize
(I had this issue just with lite-server or any  server that work with dist folder)